# Angular Date array creation with date range and time intervals

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datetime

I am trying to create an option for user to get possible visit times between two user-chosen dates, 8:00-17:00 every day.

**For example:** Between 1 Sep to 4 Sep, return [1.09.20 8:00, 1.09.20 8:15 ..., 4.09.20 16:45].

My initial thought was to create two loops, with one iterating through days, second times, but soon I realized Date is not really cooperating with me. Later on I stumbled upon this piece of code to generate just days, without iterating through times, but it was not working for me:

```
let dates: Date[];
const theDate = new Date(from);
while (theDate < to) {
  dates = [...dates, new Date(theDate)];
  theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 1);
}
return dates;
```

Console: (both dates from and to are working, in the log they are shown to be defined)

```
Sun Aug 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
Sat Aug 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at VisitService.getDatesBetween (visit.service.ts:31)
    at PatientVisitComponent.findVisits (patient-visit.component.ts:88)
    at PatientVisitComponent_Template_input_click_28_listener (patient-visit.component.html:49)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14315)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14350)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
```

I am open to any pre-build tools, I just need to later on filter this array, to exclude times (saved as Date, but I could change that) that are already taken, and let user to select one to book a visit.

**EDIT:** Whoops, forgot to add =[]; to the date, so it works, but only for the days. Is there any more elegant solution to do with times?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `moment` instead of `Date` object but just so we are here, here is how I would do it with `Date` Object. So first this, the `Date` object accepts input in the format( Year, Month, Days). You have to follow this in order for you date to output correctly.

```
let fromMonth = "12";
let fromDay = "02";
let fromYear = "2020";

let toMonth = "12";
let toDay = "05";
let toYear = "2020";

let from = new Date(fromYear+"-"+fromMonth+"-"+fromDay);
let to = new Date(toYear+"-"+toMonth+"-"+toDay);


let dates = [];
while (from < to) {
  dates = [...dates, new Date(from)];
  from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(dates);
```

In the example above, I have separated days, months, and years for ease of input. As you can as you gradually change the day of either one of them the output will change at per your requirement.

**Moment Version:**

```
let fromDate = "05-12-2020";
let toDate   = "11-12-2020";

//No need to input date in specific format with moment
let from = moment(fromDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
let to   = moment(toDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');


let dates = [];
while (moment(from).isBefore(to)) {
  dates = [...dates, new Date(from)];
  from = moment(from).add(1,'days'). format('DD-MM-YYYY'); //====> equivalent to from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(dates);
```